# IOS SAFARI ISSUE: Local test server redirects(in a loop) my server

Tags: ios, safari

When I access my website, in my QA server for testing, in a desktop using different browsers such as Chrome, Firefox and Safari the website loads just fine. When I try to access the same website using IOS safari, the page redirects in a loop. Im not sure if this is an SSL issue. Im using a self signed SSL certificate. One possible cause of the problem is that the IOS device does not accept self signed SSL.

I tried to research some possible solution. I cleared history and website data of my device and rebooted it but the same result was observed. I tried to access the website without the *https* prefix but it redirects me to the https website.

Any work around on this?

Comment: Very similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50467720/488666

Comment: I'm also seeing this issue, but can not deterministically reproduce it. It happens when I use a development server (like `ng serve --ssl`) with a non-trusted certificate. Rebooting the phone solves the issue, until it happens again, later.